# Vertical Spacing in IE 7,8,9 within a Div

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, padding, margin

I have a div tag with a few other elements inside of it, as follows:

```
<div>
  <h3>Text</h3>
  <hr/>
  <ul>
    <li>Text</li>
  </ul>
  <hr/>
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
```

Between each different element in the div, I have 0 padding and margins set for all of the elements (and it is reflected in the developers tools), however in all Internet Explorer browsers there is a significant space (roughly 4-6 pixels) between each element. I've tried setting the html, body padding/margins to 0, as well as pretty much every other element above it in the DOM hierarchy, however the spacing remains. I've also tried minimizing the HTML so there are no new-lines or spaces, however it does not resolve the problem.

Any suggestions what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you make a [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) test case?

Comment: Interestingly enough I can't replicate the problem in JS Bin, I'll keep trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the issue is the `hr` element in IE... it's not treated like other HTML elements.  There are a number of solutions out there... but I couldn't get any of them to work when you want to decrease the margins.

That being said... through trial and error I managed to get negative margins for IE only rendering to work.  Can't be sure it'll work in IE<6, IE7, IE>8 (can't test).

The minimal CSS code fragment:

```
<style>
   hr {padding:0;margin:0;height:1px;border:none;color:#000;background-color:#000;}
</style>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style>hr {display:block;margin:-7px 0;}</style>
<![endif]-->
```

... I've limited it to IE8 and less since word on the web is things will change in IE9... we'll see once it can be tested :).  Note if you want to change the colour of the line, you'll need to change values of `color` and `background-color` (depending on the browser one or the other is used: [ref](http://www.sovavsiti.cz/css/hr.html))

Tested and working in:

1. IE 8.0.6001...
2. IE 6.0.2900...
3. FF 3.6.15
4. Cr 10.0.648.134

(on WinXP)

Comment: Colouring the ul green doesn't colour the extra pixels that are spaced. Also the spaces exist both above and below each hr tag. list-style-type is disc.

Comment: @Dave Hunt - I didn't notice those problematic `HR` elements - updated my answer for a solution

Comment: That did the trick, much appreciated! Not sure why that extra spacing is there in the first place though, developer tools doesn't even pick it up

Answer (score 0):

The space you are seeing is not padding, margin or border. You are seeing the " " character written that exists between each tag.

Options:

1) Set all elements to display:block or display: inline-block. 
2) Write all the tags one after the other, dismissing all SPACE or ENTER characters

Comment: He said he minimized the HTML to remove space characters (newlines too)... don't think this is it.

Comment: Yea I saw that fix recommended elsewhere and tried it without any luck